# jQuery slider having dynamic carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I created one custom jQuery slider having carousel which **ul** width is dynamically set from **li**.

I put one div id having **#bgWrapper** on body, On click carousel **li thumbnails** I changed the body background image using **#bgWrapper on rel image of li**. Like **li rel="images/bgimage/bgone.jpg"**

I want to change body background image as for thumbnails order of carousel On click of **Next / Previous arrow**.

**Here is my jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Variable Define
    var thumbWrap = $("ul#carousel");
    var thumb = $("ul#carousel>li");
    var slider = $(".sliderCont");
    var ltarrow = $(".leftArrow");
    var rtarrow = $(".rightArrow");
    var ulwidth = 0;
    var bgImg = $("#bgWrapper");



    //Remove last LI margin for set UL perfect width
    $("ul#carousel>li:last-child").css("width", "200px");



    //UL width from LI
    thumb.each(function () {
        ulwidth += $(this).width()
    });
    thumbWrap.width(ulwidth);



    //Use same LI width value on scrollLeft:
    ltarrow.click(function () {
        slider.animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=225px"
        }, {
            duration: "slow",
            easing: "easeInOutQuint"
        });
    });

    rtarrow.click(function () {
        slider.animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=225px"
        }, {
            duration: "slow",
            easing: "easeInOutQuint"
        });
    });



    //BG Image Change reflect as relation of LI
    bgImg.css("background-image", "url(images/bgimage/bgone.jpg)");
    thumb.click(function () {
        bgImg.css("background-image", "url('" + $(this).attr('rel') + "')");
    });


});
```

Here is the demo url link. http://jsfiddle.net/NwmLL/1/ 
Updated Link http://jsfiddle.net/NwmLL/2/ just add and remove one class **.liSelect** on li for knowing which li is selected.

**I solved it, Go through the url** http://jsfiddle.net/NwmLL/3/

Comment: do you want to add the functionality for Previous and Next Right?

Comment: Yes the functionality of thumb.click(function) on Previous and Next. which will change the background image of #bgWrapper. but not statically.

Comment: add class to the selected thumb by clicking the thumb . Buy clicking the next and previous button check by the class which has the  selected thumb and use the rel attribute to change the background

Comment: I understand the logic you are telling but how can I code that on my js will you please give a example to me.

Comment: before that could you add whatever you try in jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle is not running right now.. that's why I am not giving any demo fiddle link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13926/discussion-between-muthu-and-shakti)

Comment: I joined the chart room.

Comment: could you add in the http://jsbin.com?

Comment: I have create this demo link of jsfiddle, but some images which I am using on the body background on "#bgWrapper" that will not reflect. Here is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/NwmLL/

Comment: I did the same thing, when you click on thumbnails the bg changed that is fine, but when I click on next / previous arrow then the bg also need to change according to the thumbnails order.

Answer (score -1):

Check demo [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/NwmLL/5/)

I hope it may useful for you.